# why No suitable driver found for mysql message here?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

this is my code snippet,

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Delete
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("mysql:jdbc://localhost:3306/raja","root","459805");
            Statement stmt=con.createStatement();
            int count=stmt.executeUpdate("DELETE GENNU WHERE USER_ID=3;");
            if(count>0)
                System.out.println(" Ok Deletion done");
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

and when I execute it , i got like this. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

actually you have an error in your `DELETE` statement, you lack `FROM` keyword. it should be

```
DELETE FROM GENNU WHERE USER_ID=3
```

see the error, it's pointing on `DELETE`.

**UPDATE 1**

try, `jdbc:mysql` not `mysql:jdbc`

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/raja"
              + "user=root&password=459805");
```

- [MySQL and JAVA JDBC](http://www.vogella.com/articles/MySQLJava/article.html)

Comment: No , its not working . I think command is proper because :http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-statement-example-delete-a-record/

Comment: maybe it's a typo, `DELETE` statement should have a `DELETE`, `FROM` keyword and a tableName. i'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

[The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) says:

```
        // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
        // broken Java implementations

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
```

Also, the URL should be

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost/3306/raja
```

and not

```
mysql:jdbc://localhost/3306/raja
```

Comment: Sorry ,It not working . error: unreported exception InstantiationException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                                                  ^
1 error

Comment: It's not *compiling*, because you forgot to handle the exception. That said, I think the main problem is the wrong URL. Try by changing the URL first. And read [the tutorial about exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/). That's basic stuff that you should know before using JDBC.

Comment: I have changed the URL and solved half part,Thank you and remaining part of the problem was solved by @Kuya John .

Answer (score 0):

You need the mySQL Java Connector. Which you can find at the download page here:

https://www.mysql.com/products/connector/

Comment: Thank you for answer but I already have it and placed in the path with -cp .

Comment: If the JDBC Driver would not be in the classpath, there would be an exception throwed : **ClassNotFoundException**, from this instruction : `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");`.

Comment: And MySql JDBC Drivers can also be easily found with Maven : [Maven Repo Search](http://search.maven.org/#search|gav|1|g%3A%22mysql%22%20AND%20a%3A%22mysql-connector-java%22)